# A theorem on p-adic power series

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is a question about a proof of a theorem in many books on $p$-adic numbers and I don't seem to understand one of the directions. The theorem is

Let $f(X) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nX^n \in \mathbb{Q}_p[[X]]$ be a $p$-adic power series. Let $c \in D_f$, the domain of convergence for $f$, so $f(c)$ converges. Define $g_m$ by

$g_m = \sum\limits_{n \geq m} \left(\begin{array}{c} n\\m\end{array} \right)a_nc^{n-m}$

and set $g(X) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty g_mX^m.$ Then $D_f = D_g$ (the domain of convergence of $g$) and further, for all $b \in D_f$, we have $f(b+c) = g(b).$

I have no problem with the proof that $D_f \subseteq D_g$, it's the converse I don't understand. Every resource I've gone to has said the argument is symmetric and follows from reversing the roles of $f$ and $g$. I don't see why this is true. The whole argument to show that $D_f \subseteq D_g$ is given by controlling the term

$\left| \left(\begin{array}{c} n\\m\end{array} \right)a_nc^{n-m}b^m\right|_p$

where $b \in D_f$. But when I try to do this for $b \in D_g$, I can't get the same bound. In fact, what I get is that the above term is bounded by $|a_n|_p\rho^n$ where $\rho$ satisfies $|c|_p \leq \rho$ and $|b|_p \leq \rho$ and I see no reason why this term should go to zero, and further I don't see how this plays off of any symmetry in the proof. Any help to get my understanding what I'm misinterpreting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it is ill-advised to write it as $f(c)<+\infty$, since the $p$-adics aren't ordered. There might be a one-point compactification, but that's very different.

Comment: Ah, that's just my shorthand for saying the series converges. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

That must surely be the least intuitive way possible of stating that simple result. To understand what’s happening, you should do some hand computation on series. Let me show you:

If you expand out $f(X+c)$, just go as far as, maybe the $X^4$-terms, you’ll see that $g(X)=f(X+c)$. Now, the domain of convergence of $f$ is a group $S$, and your hypothesis is that $c$ is in $S$. Since $S-c=S$, the numbers that make $g$ converge are exactly the numbers that make $f$ converge. That’s all there is to it. Of course you do have to justify my statement “you’ll see that...”.

**EDIT — Expansion**:

If you believe your own proof that $D_f\subseteq D_g$, and that for every $z\in D_f$, $f(z+c)=g(z)$, then it still seems to me that you’re done. Let $f(X+c)=\sum_{n\ge0}b_nX^n=g(X)$, and do the same thing in reverse, $h(X)=g(X-c)=\sum_{n\ge0}\beta_nX^n$, so by your result, $D_g\subseteq D_h$. Now from the evaluation part, $h(X)-f(X)$ is a power series that vanishes at every $z\in D_f$, and thus is the zero power series, so that $h=f$, $D_h=D_f$, and thus $D_g=D_f$.

Comment: This is probably a basic result in $p$-adic analysis, but why is the domain of convergence of a power series an additive group?

Comment: @A.P., it has nothing to do with $p$-adic analysis, it’s the fact that the set defined by $|z|<a$ or $|z|\le a$ is a group: that’s the ultrametric property that $|x+y|\le\max(|x|,|y|)$.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that the domain of convergence is defined by $\|z\| < a$...

Comment: @Lubin, thank you for the answer, but maybe I was not clear with what I am missing. I understand that we can rearrange the power series and that $f(X+c) = g(X)$. The justification of the "you'll see that" statement is what is confusing me, and I don't see the natural symmetry. Every resource I have seen says "reversing the argument with $g$ instead of $f$ the converse is clear". This is what I don't understand. When I try to do this, I always come back to requiring $|a_n|_p \rho \to 0$ where $\rho = \max\{ |b|_p, |c|_p\}$ with $b \in D_g$, which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Since $f(X)=g(X-c)$, the symmetry ought to be clear, no? As to the identity between $f(X+c)$ and $g(X)$, did you do the hand computation?

Comment: @Lubin, yes I've done the computation and I know the series are the same after formally rearranging terms. I'm under the impression though that this is not enough to conclude anything once we start "plugging in" values for $X$. Take for instance composition of these power series. If we can make sense of $f(g(X))$ (if $g(0) = 0 $) and assign to it a series that works at a formal level, but that series doesn't always converge to $f(g(x))$ without strict conditions on convergence of $g(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I think that a bit more needs to be said than I gave you. Let me think about this: the way I look at it, it’s an almost trivial problem when $|c|$ is less than the radius of convergence, but if your series is convergent out to and including the radius, so to speak, and $|c|$ is equal to that radius, things get a little dicier.

Comment: @Lubin (sorry about leaving this as an answer, I registered and now it won't let me leave a comment) Even if $|c|_p$ is less than the radius of convergence, I don't see how this allows us to trivially deduce what we need. Like I say I understand the rearrangement works formally. But if we could immediately use that $f(X+c) = g(X)$ to deduce something in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then I have to suspect that the proofs I have seen of this theorem would do this right away instead of appealing to a theorem on when we can switch a double sum. This is what I'm trying to invoke (and what supposedly follows fro

Comment: I’m held back because I don’t know precisely how your $D_f$ is defined. This really deserves a careful treatment, not appropriate for an extended Answer, and most certainly not for Comments. If you’re interested in pursuing this more fully, please e-mail me.

Comment: @Lubin your extended answer has answered my question, though I am still hesitant about something. I fully intend to email you about this, though at present my computer is not working and I'd like to include some latex. Thank you for your efforts though! It is appreciated.